# Scala, ZIO - how to convert ZIO to Task and get result?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, zio

I have a method which returns some ZIO:

```
def method(...): ZIO[Any with clock, SomeError, Unit]
```

The method which calls this return `Task[Unit]`:

```
def otherMethod(..): Task[Unit] = {
   ZIO.effect(method(...))
}
```

The problem is when I call it with `ZIO.effect` I don't get result.
How I should convert `ZIO` to `Task` to get result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `ZIO.effect(method(...))`  you get back a `Task[ZIO[...]]` that is rarely what you want (it's conceptually similar to a nested `Future[Future[A]]`).

In order to turn a `ZIO[R, E, A]` into a `Taks[A]`, you have to understand that the latter is just a type alias for `ZIO[Any, Throwable, A]`, which suggest that you have to

- eliminate the dependency on the environment `R` (by providing it)
- turn the error type `E` to `Throwable` if it's not already a sub-type of it (e.g. by `.mapError`)

This should work:

```scala
def otherMethod(..): Task[Unit] =
  method(...)
    .mapError(someError => new RuntimeException(s"failed with: $someError"))
    .provideLayer(Clock.live)
```

Comment: Small point but conceptually it is more similar to a `Future[() => Future[A]]` since a `Future[Future[A]]` is already processing even if not flattened, whereas `Task[Task[A]]` will do no meaningful work unless it gets flattened